# How to get users/group list on active directory in .net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, .net-core

Working on a project, where all users are created in active directory under a domain.

What I want is get all users that are in the domain, is this possible?

I am new to active directory, using .net core2.0.

Any suggestions and guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried prior to asking your question?

Comment: just login with active directory in my application.

Answer (score 11):

There is an implementation of `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` for .NET Core 2, published by the .Net Foundation. See the nuget reference [here](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-core/package/nuget/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/4.5.0-preview1-25726-06)

This will allow you to make calls like this:

```
    using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain")){
        var myDomainUsers = new List<string>();
        var userPrinciple = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
        using (var search = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrinciple)){
            foreach (var domainUser in search.FindAll()){
                if (domainUser.DisplayName != null){
                    myDomainUsers.Add(domainUser.DisplayName);
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Exact what i was looking for...
You can use the Microsoft Graph API to interact with the data users in the Microsoft cloud(Including AAD).
Link here
[Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/azure_ad_overview)