# Is there any way to get EmployeeID in .NET Core without third party libraries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I used to use the UserPrincipal class to retrieve active directory information on a user, specifically the EmployeeId (not the username, we don't usually use that to tie employees to specific data points in sql). However, in .net core that class doesn't exist and I'm still fairly new to .net core so I'm not sure how a lot of it's features work in an Intranet setting. I know many probably won't work with asp.net core being cross platform and other server types not having any idea of active directory.

Below is code I use in regular asp.net environments to grab an employee id.

```
var userContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
PrincipalContext pcxt = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com");
UserPrincipal uPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pcxt, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userContext.User.Identity.Name);
return uPrincipal.EmployeeId;
```

What kind of code if any can I use to grab the same information? Is it possible without third party libraries? It seems the IIS server may transport some kind of information I need through claims? I've attempted to do research but every thing just leads me down more research avenues and I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like for .net core 2> Microsoft has implemented the Principal Context library again, even though the documentation says there is no page when clicking .NET Core 2.2. At the very least, I am able to install the package and it works. It's authored by Microsoft, so I don't consider it Third Party.

https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-core/package/nuget/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Luckily was able to find the package thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49773749/5245385

The code is the exact same as it is in my question. All functionality seems intact.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for now has moved in Net Core. The User Principal lives on the HttpContext, but you access via the IHttpContextAccessor which is injected using dependency injection.. This is an example from Microsoft of the starting point for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks, however I understand how to use dependency injection to grab the HttpContext object in other classes other than the controllers. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to grab the employee id (not username which the user context on the httpcontext provides) since it's my understanding that data point is specific to Active Directory.

Comment: We may be talking about the same thing, I might just be ignorant on how to get from the HttpContext to the active directory information I'm looking for since I've only really dealt with the UserPrincipal class in .NET. You can see at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.2 it says that class is not available in Core 2.2

Comment: So the way I would handle this is by using the “claims” mechanism.. It allows you to add and extract specific claims from an HttpContext depending on how you code them. Exactly how you add them depends on your chosen authentication method

Comment: The chosen method currently is windows authentication. In the launchSettings.json I have the iisSettings set to : windowsAuthentication: true, anonymousAuthentication: false. There is no additional setup in the Startup.cs for the services.